# Use of Datatables in WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, serialization, datatable, dataset

I have a web applications consuming data access from the `WCF` services. around 70% of the data comes as list or `Collections` and remaining from a `Datatable`. I am experiencing some performance(speed) issue while the loading the screen.

After searching on internet i found datatable slows downs the speed 6 times than the collections. For using Collections I need to have entity class for all those. I want to serialise or make collection of datatables so that they can tranfer little fast thorugh the netwrok. What would be the efficient way to do this. In case of `serialization` or converting it to `collection`? Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you *sure* that this is the cause of your speed issue? In my experience, the slowest part of a web application is unnecessary bloat in the web page itself, e.g. excessive viewstate, overly complex markup, non-minified JavaScript, etc. Have you run your app through a profiler?

Comment: Do you mean you are sending data tables from the WCF service?

Comment: @hugh : Yes. Some of methods return Datatable

Comment: This is bad practise - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could try an Entity Model with POCOs in the [Entity Framework 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DataTableSurrogate, it is also used in the SyncFramework for serializing DataTables.

[MSDN Data Table Surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.datatablesurrogate.aspx)